# OpenGL Rendering 2D in a 3D space

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, 2d, orthographic

Am currently working on a project as part of my coursework and realised I needed to have a HUD to display information to the user, stumbled upon glOrtho and have been trying to use it however am having some issues with it as it's rendering the 2D point at the moment but not the all the 3D objects in the background.
Have made different functions for drawing 2D and 3D so the main draw function is less cluttered.

```
void draw3D
{
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  GLfloat ambientLight[] = {0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f};
  glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);

  GLfloat lightColor[] = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f};
  GLfloat lightPos[] = {-2 * floorSize, floorSize, 4 * floorSize, 1.0f};
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(60.0, (float)resizeWindowW/(float)resizeWindowH, 1.0, 50000000000.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity(); 
  glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -9.0f);      

  Cam.setView();

  glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

  oldRocket();
  drawEarth();
}
```

.

```
void draw2D()
{
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  //glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(-windowW/2, windowW/2, -windowH/2, windowH/2, -1000.0, 1000.0);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  drawCrosshair();
}
```

.

```
void drawScene() 
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  draw3D();
  draw2D(); 

  //glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

All it's drawing at the moment is the point in the middle of the screen with a black background, and have been trying to get it to draw properly for some time now with no result.
Have followed this approach as it worked on rendering the point where as before I just had the black screen.

- clean the screen
- 3D:

  - enable lighting, z-test, etc
  - set active matrix mode to projection
  - load identity and establish a perspective projection
  - set active matrix mode back to modelview
  - draw everything 3D
- 2D:

  - disable lighting, z-test, etc
  - set active matrix mode to projection
  - load identity and establish an ortogonal projection
  - set active matrix mode back to modelview
  - draw everything 2D
- swap buffers

Updated code with the perspective matrix, and it now displays properly.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: In draw2D() you disable the depth test. In the next draw3D() is it still disabled according to your code? You might have to enable it in draw3D(). Also, the glOrtho() arguments might have to be -w/2,+w/2,-h/2,+h/2,...; so the world origin is at the center of your viewport.

Comment: Enabled depth test and changed the coords to center screen and that didn't do anything.

Comment: Your modelview matrix is never really set up properly in the code pasted so far. It looks like you just accumulate up transformations between frames (and between the 2D and 3D drawing). Also, that stray `glEnd()` in `drawScene()` looks very disturbing to me.

Comment: the glEnd() was left there accidentally from a function and does nothing atm, didn't break anything, and as far as a modelview matrix is concerned I believe that is in a higher version of opengl ? am currently using the default version which is like 1.2 or something similar.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the current state of the code? In draw3D() the view matrix is set to the identity matrix. You have to set up a perspective projection matrix each time you switch those matrices. Another way is to use the matrix stack (glPushMatrix(), glPopMatrix() with the respective matrix mode activated). The same applies to the modelview matrix as derhass pointed out. Direct support for modelview and projection matrices is part of the old-school fixed function pipeline of OpenGL since 1.0 .

Comment: Updated the code and added the perspective matrix, it displays properly although need to mess around a bit with light and make the 2D object a bit more bright.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the perspective matrix between matrices fixed the problem and everything now displays properly.